# Is there a standard way to tell brew (homebrew package manager for Mac OS) to build combined 32/64-bit binaries?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

Is there a standard way to tell brew to compile libraries with "fat" 32/64 combination libraries? I'd like to build libxml2 for combo 32/64 bit?

```
/usr/local/lib/libxml2.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I can do it if I build the library "by hand", but I'm wondering if there's some convention for brew and brew formula to tell brew to do this.

Comment: If `--universal` doesn't work, you can also often do `brew edit [package]`, then add `ENV.universal_binary` in the line directly after `def install`. Save the file, then do `brew install [package]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way. Some formulae have a `--universal` option for doing this (but not all of them).